# Prevent duplicate rows with different queries

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a products grid. In this grid there's a product called "Scarf XY".
Now a user wants to search for all items with similar name, so she types in a live-search box the word "Scarf X", and it will be performed an async request to retrieve from DB all rows that match that word.
I would like to prevent the new query to return again the row for "Scarf XY".

Is there a way to, let's say, "keep track" of already returned rows even from different queries?

(Sorry for my english)

Forgot to mention: every item returned from the DB is preserved in a local Array, that's why every new query may cause duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with MySQL subqueries, but if this is meant for a site, this will be  inefficient. For example, a user may type in search terms and then delete them. Such a system you described would result in eight SQL queries for a search of "Scarf XY", which will put an unnecessary load on your database server.

A more modern and resource efficient way of doing this would be to supply the browser a JSON array and use something like [Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) from Twitter to display the information in a search bar client-side.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering. But I explained very bad what I'm looking for. The real problem is: the user type in "Scarf X", a request is performed and an item called "Scarf XZ" is returned from DB. Then the user delete the term from the search box, thus unfiltering the grid. Then she clicks on "load more products", so a new request of 10 rows is performed. I want to prevent "Scarf XZ" to be selected again from DB as I have it already on local cache. Is it possible?